# Full execution history of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execution-time

I am wondering how to get the `execution_time` for **all executions** for a specific stored procedure. (using Microsoft SQL Server 2016)

I know that via `dm_exec_procedure_stats` I get information about the `last_execution_time` and `execution_count` but I am interested in the `execution_time` of every execution (of one stored procedure) which got counted for the `execution_count`.

What I get is something like this (as an example):

```
| name     | database_id | execution_count | last_execution_time |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| sp_name1 | db_id1      | 23              | 11.09.2019 hh:mm:ss |
| sp_name2 | db_id1      | 12              | 09.09.2019 hh:mm:ss |
| sp_name3 | db_id2      | 3456            | 11.09.2017 hh:mm:ss |
```

So basically I want a query to get a table which has in one column the name of the procedure and in the other the execution times of this procedure such that the number of rows should equal the `execution_count` from the procedure.

What I want is something like this:

```
| name     | database_id | execution_time      |
------------------------------------------------
| sp_name1 | db_id1      | 11.09.2019 hh:mm:ss |
| sp_name1 | db_id1      | dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss |
| sp_name1 | db_id1      | dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss |
| ...      | ...         | ...                 |
```

which should have 23 rows.

Comment: You'll need a trace to capture every execution. I suggest a trace of `module_start` events to a rollover file target. You can them bulk insert into a table for longer-term storage and/or downstream processing. The size and number of files will need to be sufficient for the activity between that ETL process. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a48496ac-b3a3-444c-92b6-c2a9219c758e/ps-extended-events-read) for PowerShell example code snippets..

Comment: The fact you are asking this particular question might mean you have an XY problem. Why do you care about this SP? Wouldn't you be better off opening QueryStore and looking at what your highest consumers are?

Answer (score 0):

To get the  execution history of a stored procedure you can use :

**Profiler** : 
SQL Server >Tools>SQL Server Profiler
Navigate to File > New Trace. 
 Trace Properties  > click on the Events Selection tab > select the `SP:Completed counter` in the Stored Procedures grouping of counters >click on the General Tab to save the results (table / file).>Columns Filters: you can capture the database that you are working on> Finally Run

Comment: Thank you. Tried it. So that means I (1) cannot specify a specific procedure in the Profiler and (which would be better) (2) cannot use a sql script to automatically get those informations ? (yet I couldn't apply the code @Dan Guzman linked; maybe this answers my questions)

Comment: @lesem check this : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/

Comment: you'd be better using extended events.

Comment: @MitchWheat Tell us how and why, buddy-bro

Comment: @Musilix : or you could do a quick search and find lots of info on why extended events are the way to go.

Comment: @MitchWheat ok mr.wheat